# Returning a 0 count from a FROM_UNIXTIME

Tags: php, mysql

### Background

This is the API that powers a frontend Highcharts installation. A user has the option to select a "day" (24 hours), a week (7 days), or a custom interval, with no limitations. The x-axis (dates/time) needs to be completely dynamic due to the nature of the date range selected (this has been completed).

### Y-Axis

The way we're calculating the X-Axis (dates) is working pretty good, but we're having trouble returning a null value on a certain day.

We're using this query to calculate the values:

```
SELECT COUNT(u.videoid)                   AS metric, 
       FROM_UNIXTIME(u.TIME, '%M %e, %Y') AS `sqltime` 
FROM   videos u 
WHERE  ( u.TIME >= 1291179600 
         AND u.TIME <= 1293858000 ) 
       AND u.channel = '48' 
GROUP  BY `sqltime` 
ORDER  BY `sqltime` ASC
```

Here is a sample output:

```
metric  sqltime 
2   December 13, 2010
9   December 14, 2010
1   December 15, 2010
7   December 16, 2010
32  December 17, 2010
10  December 18, 2010
6   December 19, 2010
17  December 20, 2010
19  December 21, 2010
10  December 22, 2010
20  December 23, 2010
8   December 24, 2010
9   December 26, 2010
33  December 27, 2010
29  December 28, 2010
24  December 29, 2010
34  December 30, 2010
11  December 31, 2010
```

The problem is that it's not returning a value of December 25th (with 0 as the value of metric). This is causing Highcharts to skip over the value entirely, instead of showing a 0. So here's what the graph looks like currently:

[image: Sample]

But it really should look something like this:
[image: Corrected]

Where the red line is at. The only way to do that is by returning a value of 0 for December 25th, 2010 (as an example).

### Question

So the question again is, how do I modify my query to return a value of 0, for when there is no row in the `videos` table for that date/time and WHERE criteria?

### Further Info

Here is how we are currently calculating the x-axis:

```
    public function getCordinateCount()
    {
        $totalTime = $this->endTime - $this->startTime;

        // 86400 seconds in a day.
        $days = ceil($totalTime / 86400);

        if($days <= 1) {
            return 'FROM_UNIXTIME( u.time, \'%M %e, %Y %H:00\') AS `sqltime`';
        } elseif ($days < 60) {
            return 'FROM_UNIXTIME( u.time, \'%M %e, %Y\') AS `sqltime`';
        } else {

            return 'DATE_FORMAT(
                        SUBDATE(
                          FROM_UNIXTIME( u.time ),
                          INTERVAL WEEKDAY( FROM_UNIXTIME( u.time ) ) DAY
                        ),
                        \'%M %e, %Y\') as `sqltime`';
        } 

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try having a table DAYS with all days (from 1st of January to 31 of December).

Then do a LEFT JOIN. If the metric is null, then the result is ZERO =>

```
SELECT IF(tmp.metric IS NULL,0,tmp.metric),DAYS.datestr FROM DAYS LEFT JOIN (
SELECT COUNT(u.videoid)                   AS metric, 
       FROM_UNIXTIME(u.TIME, '%M %e, %Y') AS `sqltime` 
FROM   videos u 
WHERE  ( u.TIME >= 1291179600 
         AND u.TIME <= 1293858000 ) 
       AND u.channel = '48' 
GROUP  BY `sqltime` 
) tmp ON DAYS.datestr=tmp.`sqltime`
ORDER  BY `sqltime` ASC
```

(I suppose here DAYS.datestr have the same format as sqltime).

That's how I would do it in the QUERY. But I really would do it in PHP, first set the whole array to 0 values , and then merge it with the result of the query.

HIH

Comment: The problem with the query is having a table just for DAYS, when that's entirely dynamic. Definitely not efficient at all. Until a better solution is found, I'll go with a PHP array that iterates through  to make sure no date is missing.